# How do I send text-to-speech to a google home device?

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

I have DialogFlow sending a Fulfillment webhook to my server and I am able to send a text-to-speech response back to the google home device.

But how do I trigger a text-to-speech message to be read out by the device without having to initiate from the google home device?

I saw this question on SO which implies it's possible:
[Send audio file to DialogFlow using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514322/send-audio-file-to-dialogflow-using-python)

I haven't been able to get his code to work because I don't know how to link the userId/sessionId that I get in my webhook call to the `request.session_id` used in the example.

```
request = ai.text_request()
request.lang = 'de'  # optional, default value equal 'en'
request.session_id = "<SESSION ID, UNIQUE FOR EACH USER>"
request.query = "Hello"
response = request.getresponse()
print (response.read())
```

I also found a CURL to trigger an event, but again I can't seem to link the sessionId in the url to my device.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" 
"https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910&e=event_name&timezone=Europe/Paris
&lang=en&sessionId=1234567890"`

Comment: Can someone tell me what these examples (`ai.text_request()` and `event triggering`) are used for?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a freeware program called 'cast' ( [www.rlatour.com/cast](http://www.rlatour.com/cast) ) and to get around this problem the program converts the text to an audio file, and then casts the audio file to the google device

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for a Google Home device to read out something without some sort of user initiation. There is no equivalent to a push notification on the speakers.